# Ruby on Rails Slim views populating with html, link and scripts before code entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a sample RoR application, and when creating views using slim, I am seeing in the source a lot of pre-populated code, that appears before the code I write.  For example:

I write this:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title Music | Home

    body
        h1 Music
        p   This is the home page for 

        a href='http://music.com' Music
```

The output in the source I get is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Myapp</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/microposts.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/microposts.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/users.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="+VujoWSILml72WaDcfJHc+ZgrtuZEIA/pCsFbDASXWo=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Music | Home</title></head><body><h1>Music </h1><p>   This is the home page for </p><a href="http://music.com">Music</a></body></html>

</body>
</html>
```

Clearly there is something pre-populating the view with all of the link and script tags and the doc type etc.., that wraps around what I actually wrote.  How do I remove this?  And what is populating this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical Rails controller render your view file inside layout file. So take a look at `app/views/layouts/application.html.slim`. This file will include your view file at `yield` call when rendering HTML. So you do not need to create some common elements like header or footer in every view. Usually it's enough to put them in layout.

I think it's better to read the guides before asking so very basic questions

1. [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html)
2. [Action View Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: Ah good call, just not used to having the layout having pre-populated code.  Sorry for wasting your time.